Consumir un servicio soap que responde con un dataset (diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata) - Java
Recientemente me encontré con una necesidad de consumir un servicio soap, en el cual una de las operaciones tenía como elemento de respuesta un <any/>, y que cuando consumía esta operación, recibía la definición de la estructura (o schema) que comprendía a "any" y a su vez la data respondida con esa estructura, lo cual me supuso un reto, dado que cuando generaba las clases con wsimport desde el wsdl, estas me mapeaban un objeto con nombre any. Investigando encontré que esto se debía a un tipo especial de .Net, por lo que no había (y entiendo que no sigue habiendo) una forma desarrollada en algún paquete para dicho consumo.
Respuesta según wsdl para dicha operación.
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <EjecutarConsultaXMLResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <EjecutarConsultaXMLResult>
        <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</EjecutarConsultaXMLResult>
    </EjecutarConsultaXMLResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>

Ejemplo de respuesta del consumo:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <EjecutarConsultaXMLResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <EjecutarConsultaXMLResult>
            <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
               <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                  <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="Resultado">
                           <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                 <xs:element name="NOMBRE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="APELLIDO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="GENERO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="NIVEL_ESTUDIOS" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                 <xs:element name="F_NACIMIENTO" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0"/>
                              </xs:sequence>
                           </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                     </xs:choice>
                  </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
            </xs:schema>
            <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
              <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                  <Resultado diffgr:id="Resultado1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                     <NOMBRE>Fabian</NOMBRE>
                     <APELLIDO>Pallares</APELLIDO>
                     <GENERO>M</GENERO>
                     <NIVEL_ESTUDIOS>Profesional</NIVEL_ESTUDIOS>
                     <F_NACIMIENTO>1991/01/05</F_NACIMIENTO>
                  </Resultado>
               </NewDataSet>
            </diffgr:diffgram>
         </EjecutarConsultaXMLResult>
      </EjecutarConsultaXMLResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Por lo anterior desarrollé una solución temporal por si a alguien le puede servir en el futuro. La anexo en las respuestas.

Para el anterior problema, la solución aplicada fue recibir y castear la respuesta dentro de un objeto tipo org.w3c.dom.Node, ejemplo:
var resultNode = ((Node) response.getEjecutarConsultaXMLResult().getAny()).getFirstChild()

Posterior a eso, creé un DTO que mapeara la estructura que recibo:
@JsonRootName("Resultado")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ResultExecuteConsultClientResponse implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty(value = "NOMBRE")
    private String NOMBRE;
    ...
}

Y luego implementé un método canónico que recibiera dicho nodo y la clase DTO referenciada, y regresara el DTO poblado con la data del nodo:
public static <T> T convertNodeToObject(Node node, Class<T> valueType) throws TechnicalTransformationException {
        String xmlString = nodeToString(node);
        try {
            return XML_OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(xmlString, valueType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new TechnicalTransformationException(String.format("Error converting node to object: %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

private static String nodeToString(Node node) throws TechnicalTransformationException {
        try {
            javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource source = new javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource(node);
            java.io.StringWriter writer = new java.io.StringWriter();
            javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult result = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(writer);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
            return writer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new TechnicalTransformationException(String.format("Error converting node to string: %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

Siendo XML_OBJECT_MAPPER una instancia de com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper.
¡Espero que les sirva!
